# React Redux - Showing Dialog after posting data not working - Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'openDialog' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am very new to react-redux. I am trying to get an dialogbox to show "data posted successfully" upon posting of data through api. I want to achieve it through:

```
this.insertSingleUser(postData).then(function () {
            console.log("user inserted");
            this.openDialog("Data posted successfully");
        });
```

Everything is working fine except this piece,  data is being posted, console result is being shown but the dialog box `this.openDialog("Data posted successfully");` is not opening.

However dialogbox will open if called outside of `this.insertSingleUser(postData).then(function () {` .

Please suggest me what i am doing wrong over here. Full code is pasted below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { postUser } from '../redux/user/userActions';
import AlertDialog from '../reusables/AlertDialog';

class UsersContainerPost extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            first_name: '',
            last_name: '',
            phone: '',
            email: '',
            address: '',
            city: '',
            state: '',
            message: '',
            dialogIsOpen: false,
            dialogHeaderText: '',
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    openDialog = (dialogHeaderMessage) => {
        this.setState({
            dialogIsOpen: true,
            dialogHeaderText: dialogHeaderMessage
        })
    }

    closeDialog = () => {
        this.setState({
            dialogIsOpen: false
        })
    }

    handleChange = (field, event) => {
        this.setState({ [field]: event.target.value })
    }

    async insertSingleUser(postData) {
        return this.props.insertUser(postData);
    }


    handleSubmit(event) {
        // alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.name);
        event.preventDefault();
        const {
            first_name,
            last_name,
            phone,
            email,
            address,
            city,
            state
        } = this.state;

        const postData = {
            first_name: first_name,
            last_name: last_name,
            phone: phone,
            email: email,
            address: address,
            city: city,
            state: state
        };

        // console.log(this.state);
        // console.log(postData);
        // alert('hi');

        // this.props.insertUser(postData);
        //     console.log("user inserted");

        this.insertSingleUser(postData).then(function () {
            console.log("user inserted");
            this.openDialog("Data posted successfully");
        });


        console.log("message" + this.props.message);
        // (this.props.message) ? this.openDialog("Data posted successfully") : this.openDialog("Data POst error");



    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Add New User</h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <div>
                        <label>First Name:</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            value={this.state.first_name}
                            onChange={(event, newValue) => this.handleChange('first_name', event)} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Last Name:</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            value={this.state.last_name}
                            onChange={(event, newValue) => this.handleChange('last_name', event)} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Phone:</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            value={this.state.phone}
                            onChange={(event, newValue) => this.handleChange('phone', event)} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Email:</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            value={this.state.email}
                            onChange={(event, newValue) => this.handleChange('email', event)} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div>
                    Notice Message : {this.props.message}
                </div>
                <div>
                    <Link to='/'>Go Home</Link>
                </div>
                {/* {this.props.message ? (<AlertDialog open={this.state.dialogIsOpen} onClose={this.closeDialog} />) : ('')} */}
                <AlertDialog
                    headerMessage={this.state.dialogHeaderText}
                    open={this.state.dialogIsOpen}
                    onClose={this.closeDialog}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    // console.log(state.user.successMessage);
    return {
        message: state.user.successMessage
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        insertUser: postData => dispatch(postUser(postData))
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UsersContainerPost);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an arrow function so the parent `this` is accessible from inside `.then()` callback.

Like this:

```js
this.insertSingleUser(postData).then(() => {
  console.log("user inserted");
  this.openDialog("Data posted successfully");
});
```

So instead of `this.insertSingleUser(postData).then(function() {...})` with the function keyword, you use `this.insertSingleUser(postData).then(() => {...})` with the arrow function